# Wireless keyboard not working but mouse is. How do you address this issue? Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, usb, keyboard

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and my usb for this set of devices is listed as:
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 062a:4c01 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. 2,4Ghz Wireless Transceiver [for Delux M618 Plus Wireless Vertical Mouse] under lusb terminal command.
The mouse works great but any wireless usb mouse keyboard combo suffers the same issue. Keyboard not working. Shortly before it stopped working, the keyboard would stick on a letter and spam it several times. (sssssssssssssssssssss). Then shortly after, if simply stopped working. I have ran sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade and rebooted. Then I ran:
sudo modprobe -r usbhid && sudo modprobe usbhid And rebooted as well with no effect in either case. I am curious if anyone has had this issue and found a solution. Thank you in advance for your help and if further info is required, please let me know.
P.S. The keyboard mouse combo in question is Multilaser TC502 but I could not find any drivers for this device.
A wired keyboard works fine.

Comment: Try replacing the batteries in the keyboard.

Comment: and a wired keyboard? Does that have the same effect? Don't add additional info to the comment trail, [edit] your post. Further, you are silent on which input source you have selected.

Comment: @user535733 I appologize. I assumed it was you who downvoted me.

Comment: @graham. A wired keyboard works just fine. It is just the wireless that is giving me trouble.